# Probability of same birthday

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification, birthday

I think I solved this problem but I would like to know if I am right or wrong, I am not quite sure.

We assume that the year has 365 days and the birthdays are uniformly distributed. We want to find out what's the probability that at least 2 of n people share the same birthday.
So my sample space would be: $$\Omega = \left \{ (w_{1},... ,w_{n}) | n \geq 2, w_{i}\in{1,... ,365} \right \}$$
$$|\Omega| = 365^{n}$$

Let $A$ be the event that at least 2 people share the same birthday.
Let $A_{0}$ be the event that no people share the same birthday/n people were born on different days.
$\Rightarrow |A_{0}| = \binom{365}{n}$
This implies:
$$P(A) = P(A_{0}^{c}) = 1- P(A_{0}) = 1-\frac{\binom{365}{n}}{365^{n}}$$
Is this true? Or where did I go wrong? The thing that I am really not sure about is the cardinality of $\Omega$.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Looks good to me. Please note that [tag:probability-theory] is about more advanced topics. I removed it.

Comment: I think that your counting does not take order into account, and  $|A_0| = 365!/(365-n)!$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the famous birthday problem, for which you should be able
to find many explanations online (some on this site).

Your answer is headed in the right direction, but the denominator
of the fraction counts ordered sequences of possible birthdays,
whereas the numerator counts unordered sequences. (So the comment
that suggest your answer 'looks good' should be reconsidered.)

If you change the numerator to the *permutations* of 365 days
taken n at a time, it should be OK. (But the comment that suggests
the numerator should be a factorial should also be reconsidered.)

If $n = 23$, the probability will be a bit larger than 1/2. In R,
this is computed as follows:

```
  1-prod(365:(365-22))/365^23
  ## 0.5072972
```

*Note:* A very common beginners' error in using combinatorics to do
probability problems is to mix unordered and ordered counts
in the same expression. It seems everyone needs to make this
mistake once. Perhaps in your case it will be *only* this once.